# Which server is affected when we use Neo4j traversal API?

Tags: neo4j, traversal

Maybe a silly question :)

If we use separate physical servers for Application and Database, when using Traversal framework, which one of the servers should support the queries (DB or Application)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j traversals run on the Neo4j database server, if you are using the server version of Neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm building a similar system right now, so my view is probably biased.

My Node.js Application server provides an Angular app from the /public folder. The client application speaks only to the Application server.

Generally it works like this: 
Client sends a message to Server.
Server returns a promise to client. 
Server queries the DB, performs any necessary manipulation to the data.
Server resolves the promise. 
Client interprets the response.

hope that's helpful.